# How can I check if a referring domain is blank?

Tags: javascript, url, referrer

I've written a bit of JavaScript that reads the referring URL of a page and loops through an object to check for strings such as "google", "msn", "bing" etc. The resulting value is stored in a variable which is then passed to a server. Now this all works perfectly but my question is around detecting traffic directly to a site (i.e. people typing the URL in the address bar). How can I detect this?

I was thinking, that I could do something like:

```
var refURL = document.referrer;
var serverVar = "";
  if (refURL === "") {
    serverVar = 'direct traffic';
   }
```

Should I be checking for `""` (i.e. blank) or should I be checking if `refURL` is `null`?

Comment: What is the problem with `if (refURL === "") {`

Comment: It'a not that its a problem, that's how I've currently coded it. What I want to know is, would this be the correct way of checking for direct traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to do the way you are comparing now as in your code, You could use:

```
//check for blank, null or undefined
function isBlank(str) {
    return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
}
var refURL = document.referrer;
var serverVar = "";
  if (isBlank(refURL)) {
    serverVar = 'direct traffic';
   }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if(!document.referrer) {}`